# Slick+HikariCP runs out of connections during extensive streaming usage

Tags: postgresql, akka, slick, hikaricp, akka-persistence

I am using [akka-persistence-jdbc](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc) plugin for Akka Persistence in some parts of application and slick directly in another parts.
After migrating the the hottest parts from direct slick usage to akka-persistence HikariCP started to throw exceptions:

```
WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.LeakTask    Connection leak detection triggered for connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3a3c8d5d, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
```

That's not a problem of slow SQL queries. Explain analyze shows that PostgreSQL executes them in ~1 millisecond. But connection waits for something and not being released for minutes. Some more details on that are [here](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc/issues/44).

[image]

`akka-persistence-jdbc` uses streaming for writes and reads, could it be a slick bug or something is wrong in the way `akka-persistence-jdbc` [does such operations](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/jdbc/dao/bytea/ByteArrayJournalDao.scala)?

I am using slick 3.1.1, HikariCP 2.3.7, PostgreSQL 9.4 with `max_connections: 120`.